# email header parser

Tags: email, header

I want to design an email header parser using c language.
I have the email header in text format, but i don't have any idea of how to
parse and extract information from it, and what is the relevent information
to be extracted.

If anybody have an idea of any programme please inform.

Comment: If you need information concerning the structure of email headers, have a look at [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt).

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of libraries in C++ that you could use or check out for clues, like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673012/what-good-c-mail-library-would-you-recommend) or [mimetic](http://codesink.org/mimetic_mime_library.html).

I suggest you also check these out:
[RFC2821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821) and [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822)

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it is to use a regular expressions library. This is a good place to start: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html